# Pooling basic descriptives from several multiply imputed datasets (using mice)

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, multiple-imputation, pooling, mice

I am somewhat new to mice but I am trying my best. So I successfully imputed my data and created five datasets.

For the sake of simplicity, let's just use the nhanes dataset that comes with mice

```
 imp <- mice(nhanes, seed = 23109)
```

In my paper, I need to show basic descriptives (so for example: mean, standard deviation, skewness, kurtosis etc.). I understand that I can pool the parameters and results of my analysis with Rubin's rules using the following syntax:

```
fit <- with(imp, lm(chl ~ age + bmi))
print(pool(fit))

Call: pool(object = fit)
Pooled coefficients:
(Intercept) age bmi
-34.158914 34.330666 6.212025
Fraction of information about the coefficients missing due to nonresponse:
(Intercept) age bmi
0.5747265 0.7501284 0.4795427
```

**But how would I go about this to report basic descriptives?** Is there a way to combine these and a function in the mice package that does this for me, or do I have to do this manually? So for example I tried:

```
mean.fit <- with(data=imp, expr=mean(bmi))
pool(mean.fit)
```

and , I get the warning:

```
Error in pool(mean.fit) : Object has no coef() method.
```

which obviously means that is not how it should be done.

A different (and easier) possibility would be to pick just one of the imputed datasets to showcase (they are all very similar anyway. However, it feels like this wouldn't be a recommended thing to do because the whole upside of using multiple imputation should be that I am not pretending that the imputed values are the real values but that they come with a certain uncertainty.

If anyone could help me, I'd be very happy. Thanks.

Comment: I had this problem a few years ago. I cannot now remember what I did. I don't have time to dig out my archives tonight, but I'll have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to complete descriptives with no standard error around the descriptives (i.e., no confidence interval around the sample mean or sample standard deviation), you can use `complete()` to recover the imputed data sets and then perform actions on them. For example, to compute the average sample mean and variance across the imputations, you might do the following:

```
imp.data <- complete(imp, "long")
(means <- with(imp.data, tapply(bmi, .imp, mean)))
mean(means)
(variances <- with(imp.data, tapply(bmi, .imp, var)))
mean(variances)
```

If you want inference, you can manually apply Rubin's rules to the estimates.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using miceadds package if you want to calculate standard deviations etc. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/miceadds/versions/3.5-14/topics/with.miceadds

Comment: more of a comment